# How to get individual tumblr post's likes count for tumblr_client gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, tumblr

I am trying to get likes count for inidividual tumblr posts. I can only seem to get the total likes of the user and also reblog/note_count.

Refer to code below.

```
user = Authentication.where(user_id: current_user.id, provider: "tumblr").first
oauth_id = user.uid
oauth_access_token = user.token
oauth_password = user.token_secret 
client = Tumblr::Client.new(:client => :httpclient)
mytumblr = client.posts("testing.tumblr.com", :limit => 10)
mytumblr["posts"].each do |posts|
  p posts["id"]
  p posts["post_url"]
  p posts["title"]
  p posts["note_count"]
  p posts["likes"] # <--- this does not work, cause there is no "likes" in "mytumblr["posts"]"
end
```

Here is the result of the code.

```
1169662102
"http://testing.tumblr.com/post/1169682102/woe-is-me"
"Woe is me"
0
1169509367
"http://testing.tumblr.com/post/1169509307/testing-more-stuff"
"Testing more stuff"
1
1168129942
"http://testing.tumblr.com/post/1168122942/testing-more-stuff"
"Testing more stuff"
1
1168128057
"http://testing.tumblr.com/post/1168128857/erm-i-am-just-like-testing-this-thing"
"Erm, I am just like testing this thing"
0
 => [{"blog_name"=>"testing", "id"=>1166782102, "post_url"=>"http://testing.tumblr.com/post/1169682102/woe-is-me", "slug"=>"woe-is-me", "type"=>"text", "date"=>"2015-04-21 02:50:35 GMT", "timestamp"=>142958635, "state"=>"published", "format"=>"html", "reblog_key"=>"C7VHqM", "tags"=>[], "short_url"=>"http://tmblr.co/Z09YlkxmtIM", "followed"=>false, "highlighted"=>[], "liked"=>false, "note_count"=>0, "title"=>"Woe is me", "body"=>"<p>Coming up with a good means for us to get users are difficult.</p>", "can_reply"=>false}, {"blog_name"=>"testing", "id"=>116953677, "post_url"=>"http://testing.tumblr.com/post/11609367/testing-more-stuff", "slug"=>"testing-more-stuff", "type"=>"text", "date"=>"2015-04-20 23:30:43 GMT", "timestamp"=>1429572643, "state"=>"published", "format"=>"html", "reblog_key"=>"3v46jj3i", "tags"=>[], "short_url"=>"http://tmblr.co/Z09Ylk1qQo3", "followed"=>false, "highlighted"=>[], "liked"=>false, "note_count"=>1, "title"=>"Testing more stuff", "body"=>"<p><a href=\"http://testing.tumblr.com/post/1168129942/testing-more-stuff\" class=\"tumblr_blog\">testing</a>:</p>\n\n<blockquote><p>More Stuff to test</p></blockquote>\n\n<p>More happy than stuff</p>", "reblog"=>{"tree_html"=>"<p><a href=\"http://testing.tumblr.com/post/116812942/testing-more-stuff\" class=\"tumblr_blog\">testing</a>:</p><blockquote><p>More Stuff to test</p></blockquote>", "comment"=>"<p>More happy than stuff</p>", "trail"=>[{"blog"=>{"name"=>"testing", "theme"=>{"avatar_shape"=>"square", "background_color"=>"#FAFAFA", "body_font"=>"Helvetica Neue", "header_bounds"=>"", "header_image"=>"http://assets.tumblr.com/images/default_header/optica_pattern_09.png?_v=abe6f565397f54e0c2b76e6fc2022e", "header_image_focused"=>"http://assets.tumblr.com/images/default_header/optica_pattern_09_focused_v3.png?_v=abe6f565397fe880c2b76e6fc2022e", "header_image_scaled"=>"http://assets.tumblr.com/images/default_header/optica_pattern_09_focused_v3.png?_v=abe6f565397f54e8c2b76e6fc2022e", "header_stretch"=>true, "link_color"=>"#529ECC", "show_avatar"=>true, "show_description"=>true, "show_header_image"=>true, "show_title"=>true, "title_color"=>"#444444", "title_font"=>"Gibson", "title_font_weight"=>"bold"}}, "post"=>{"id"=>"116812932942"}, "comment"=>"<p>More Stuff to test</p>"}]}, "can_reply"=>false}, {"blog_name"=>"testing", "id"=>116812932, "post_url"=>"http://testing.tumblr.com/post/116932942/testing-more-stuff", "slug"=>"testing-more-stuff", "type"=>"text", "date"=>"2015-04-19 13:08:10 GMT", "timestamp"=>142944889, "state"=>"published", "format"=>"html", "reblog_key"=>"3v46jji", "tags"=>[], "short_url"=>"http://tmblr.co/Z0lk1iob_TE", "followed"=>false, "highlighted"=>[], "liked"=>false, "note_count"=>1, "title"=>"Testing more stuff", "body"=>"<p>More Stuff to test</p>", "can_reply"=>false}, {"blog_name"=>"testing", "id"=>18128057, "post_url"=>"http://testing.tumblr.com/post/181257/erm-i-am-just-like-testing-this-thing", "slug"=>"erm-i-am-just-like-testing-this-thing", "type"=>"text", "date"=>"2015-04-19 13:07:16 GMT", "timestamp"=>142948836, "state"=>"published", "format"=>"html", "reblog_key"=>"gOGpGC", "tags"=>[], "short_url"=>"http://tmblr.co/Z09Ylk1boXP", "followed"=>false, "highlighted"=>[], "liked"=>false, "note_count"=>0, "title"=>"Erm, I am just like testing this thing", "body"=>"<p>well, let me test this.</p>", "can_reply"=>false}]
```

Is there a way for me to use this gem to query for "likes" of each individual posts from "mytumblr["posts"]"?

***UPDATE***

```
Tumblr.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = ENV["TUMBLR_ID"]
  config.consumer_secret = ENV["TUMBLR_SECRET"]
  config.oauth_token = "#{oauth_access_token}"
  config.oauth_token_secret = "#{oauth_password}"
end
```

Comment: What's the output of `mytumblr["posts"]`?

Comment: Sadly its not possible. `note_count` is a combination of likes and reblogs: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts

Comment: Also @mikedidthis, I dont think note_count is a combination of likes and reblogs. Cause I check my tumblr account, there is only one reblog but there are 2 likes, however note_count result is only 1.

Comment: Do you have a link to showcase this? IIRC `note_count` doesn't count **posted this** and **like** if it your own post.

Comment: The post was obtained from oauth token after giving permission to tumblr application. The query was made through the oauth token, can refer to an update above. Is this method considered own posts?

Comment: I would imagine so. Your querying the authorised users account. I can't be 100% certain though.